# Load controller from storyboard using Cucumberish with UI Testing

Tags: swift, user-interface, testing, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to implement UI testing with BDD using [Cucumberish](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/Cucumberish) framework.
I understand quite well the Feature files parsing system and I managed to tests some UI elements of the main screen.

However I would like to load any controller from storyboard before using UI testing on the corresponding screen.

Here is my initialization code:

```
@objc class CucumberishSwiftInit: NSObject {
@objc class func CucumberishSwiftInit()
{
    var application : XCUIApplication!
    //A closure that will be executed just before executing any of your features
    beforeStart { () -> Void in
        application = XCUIApplication()
    }
    //A Given step definition
    Given("the app is running") { (args, userInfo) -> Void in
        application.launch()
        let bundle = Bundle.main

        // I double checked the storyboard name and I can access it in my Unit Tests target
        // application crashes here
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)

        // never executed 
        Swift.print("storyboard \(storyboard)")
    }
    let bundle = Bundle(for: CucumberishSwiftInit.self)

    Cucumberish.executeFeatures(inDirectory: "Features", from: bundle, includeTags: nil, excludeTags: ["skip"])
}
}
```

Some feature file:

```
@run @welcome
Feature: Some feature
Some feature desc

Scenario: Can load screen
    Given the app is running
    ...
```

The application crashed on the UIStoryboard init statement, caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded). I have no clue why as it is working using with my unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to the fact that the `.storyboard` file you are trying to load is not part of the bundle of the application you are running.

The reason that's happening is that when you run a UI test your code is not running in the same process as your application, and it can only interact with it through the `XCUIApplication` proxy. (*The mechanics might be slightly different, but that's gist, unfortunately there's little documentation that I can link.*)

UI testing is a different style of testing than what you can do with `XCTest`. Programmatically loading an instance of a screen from a `.storyboard` is not possible.

In other words, you can't use any code from your app in your UI tests, but rather have to interact with it like a real user would, and write assertions for what's on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! thus if I don't have access to the .storyboard files, I must manually go to specific screens. Also an interesting alternative here using launch arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020329/is-it-possible-to-open-a-screen-directly-in-xcuitest.
If the UI tests are intended to test the screens inner working, this is an interesting approach as it is agnostic to how the application segues evolves.

Comment: Happy to be useful @michael-martinez :)  The approach in the linked question is ingenious but comes with a lot of overhead in the production code to support the ability to run the UI test. I would encourage anyone considering implementing it to value up the cost of that extra code in their production codebase. Code is a liability, the less we can write the better.